# Cant load custom layout resource through Submodule - NoSuchFieldError - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, git-submodules

I have an Activity that is being declared from a submodule..
`java.lang.NoSuchFieldError` is thrown when I try to load a custom layout (it extends from LinearLayout) from the same submodule.  The same code will work if the layout is manually imported to the project.

```
MyCustomView customView = (MyCustomView)findViewById(R.id.customViewId);
```

It is able to findViewById for other types of objects like ListViews + Textviews, but when it hits that above Custom View find, it breaks.

```
04-02 16:40:56.851 714-714/com.myproject.xrf W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40b7d930)
04-02 16:40:56.851 714-714/com.myproject.xrf E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                            java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com.myproject.R$id.customLayoutId
                                                                at com.myproject.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:112)
                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---------Here is the custom layout-------

```
public class LinearLayoutListView extends LinearLayout {

    ListView mListView;

    public LinearLayoutListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public LinearLayoutListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public LinearLayoutListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                                int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void setListView(ListView lv) {
        mListView = lv;
    }
}
```

---

And it's being loaded here in the activity.xml:

```
<com.myproject.LinearLayoutListView
    android:id="@+id/customViewId"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]? That would include the full Java stack trace, plus your code that is referenced in that stack trace, and probably the layout resource that is triggering all of this.

Comment: Added above w/ Stacktrace + Code, and just to re-iterate the code works fine when it's imported to a main activity w/ no submodules.

Comment: This doesn't feel like it is tied to `com.myproject.LinearLayoutListView`, but instead tied to the widget ID itself. You have "It is able to findViewById for other types of objects like ListViews + Textviews". Are you referring to other widgets in `activity.xml`? Where is `activity.xml` defined (the submodule or the app)?

Comment: I was just replacing the submodule package for `LinearLayoutListView` w/ a random package name to obfuscate company details.  The Activity is defined in the submodule.. the custom layout is defined in the same submodule.

Comment: Do both the app and the module have a `com.myproject.R` class? Is this field in both of them? Does the manifest in the module have a different `package` than does the app?

Comment: The app and module have different packages.